# curCSS method error in ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am getting an error while creating an autocomplete extender using jQuery. The error occurs at the second line.

```
function reduce(elem, size, border, margin) {
    $.each(side, function () { // error on this line
        size -= parseFloat($.curCSS(elem, "padding" + this, true))
        0;

        if (border) {
            size -= parseFloat($.curCSS(elem, "border" + this + "Width", true))
            0;
        } 
        if (margin) {
            size -= parseFloat($.curCSS(elem, "margin" + this, true))
            0;
        }
    }); 
    return size;
}
```

Comment: where is `wcham marked as bold. function reduce(elem, size, border, margin) {`

Comment: should $.each(side, function () {
read $.each(size, function () {
?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? `$.curCSS()` [was removed](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11787) in v1.7.2

Comment: am using 1.8.2 varsion. am getting this error      SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'curCSS' 
jquery-ui.js, line 144 character 17

Comment: So it will not work then! Your version of jQuery does not have the function any more. You have to use a lower version of jQuery in order to use this code or rewrite it.

Answer (score 14):

From the jQuery 1.8.0 [release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/):

> $.curCSS: This method was simply an alias for jQuery.css() from jQuery 1.3 onward. Although it has never been part of the documented API, some external code has been known to use it, perhaps thinking it was "more efficient." Now it's "more gone."

Since you are using jQuery v1.8.2, the `$.curCSS()` function does not exist. You can use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) instead.

Comment: if you go and look jquery 1.8.2 source code you will still see it there. I don't get it :)

Comment: Correct! It still exists in the source but is no longer _publicly_ accessible. You can try a `console.log($.curCSS);​` with jQuery < v1.8.0 and it will return the function. The same with jQuery >= v1.8.0 it will output `undefined`